# Putting a MySQL JOIN back into the database instead of just returning the columns

Tags: mysql, join, sql-update, denormalized

I've just got a quick question about a query I'm having difficulty with. I've got two tables and I'm trying to denormalize them into one table.

Here are the two tables:

dateTable:

```
ID | Date
```

and dataTable:

```
ID | DateID | Data
```

And what I'd like to end up with is:

```
ID | DateID | Data | Date
```

What I've got right now is:

```
UPDATE dataTable
SET date = dateTable.date 
WHERE `DateID` = `dateTable.id`
```

But this is syntactically incorrect. If I did this with a JOIN, how do you put the data back into the Date column on dataTable and not just return the data?

Thanks!

Comment: What you asking is not 100% clear - are you trying to return the joined data, or are you trying to update data in one table based on criteria available from the second table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE dataTable data
JOIN dateTable dates on dates.id = data.dataId
SET data.date = dates.date;
```